# php preg_match to return the count

Tags: php, preg-match

I have these following variables:

```
$texttofind = "story of a test";
$paragraph  = "the story of a test and a test paragraph used for
               testing the story of a test paragraph";
```

I would like to use `preg_match();` to return the count, which in this case would be 2. any ideas?

Comment: `preg_match_all` by default returns the number of occurances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for regular expressions, simply use [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count):

```
echo 'Found texttofind ' . substr_count($paragraph, $texttofind) . ' times';
```

If you really want to use regular expressions, you can use the following (slower, and unnecessarily complex) expression:

```
echo preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($texttofind, '/') . '/', $paragraph);
```